# Is there a way to render scss file and string data together in NodeJS

Tags: css, node.js, node-sass

I'm `node-sass` method `renderSync` to minify Scss file to Css. But I have additional css in string format I want to concatenate the file's data and string data and then create a minified CSS, here is my try

```
var basic_file = "./app/scss/" + base_version + "/_base-app.scss";
var basic_scss = fs.readFileSync(basic_file).toString();
var basic_css = basic_scss + result[0].basic;
var different_result = sass.renderSync({
                    data: basic_css,
                    outputStyle: 'compressed'
            });
```

but as I load the file it says `'File to import not found or unreadable: _common\nParent style sheet: stdin'` and file is there and it gets loaded if I use `file` over `data` in `renderSync` and put file's directory.

Comment: shouldn't you initialize variable `basic_css` after `result`?

Comment: Edited, sorry. I have to use combination of files data that if `basic_file` and `basic_scss`

Comment: Well, as far as I understand, at this moment `basic_scss` has just a content of `basic_file`. Where is your additional css in string?

Comment: Oh I see the confusion this `result[0].basic` has the additional css string and this var `basic_css ` is meant to combine them.